# Python 3 | Appending a string to an item in a list?

Tags: python, for-loop

After trying many different methods for this problem, such as nested `for` loops (which iterate over the first list as many times as the length of the second iteration), and I've tried `.join` which I couldn't get to do what I wanted.

---

**Here is the problem...**

I am using two `for` loops to append the same list.

The first `for` loop:

```
for friend in individual_friends:
    friends.append(friend.text)
```

Which gives me:

```
['Jody Ann Elizabeth Lill\n98 mutual friends\nFriends',
 ...., 
'Jayde Woods\n56 mutual friends\n4 new posts\nFriends']
```

the second `for` loop:

```
for link in individual_friends_links:
    links = link.get_attribute("href")
    friends.append(links)
```

Which gives me:

```
['Jody Ann Elizabeth Lill\n98 mutual friends\nFriends', 
..., '
Jayde Woods\n56 mutual friends\n4 new posts\nFriends', 
'https://m.facebook.com/jodyannelizabeth.lill?ref=bookmarks', 
..., 
'https://m.facebook.com/jayde.woods?ref=bookmarks']
```

What I actually want is:

```
['Jody Ann Elizabeth Lill\n98 mutual friends\nFriends\nhttps://m.facebook.com/jodyannelizabeth.lill?ref=bookmarks', 
..., 
'Jayde Woods\n56 mutual friends\n4 new posts\nFriends\nhttps://m.facebook.com/jayde.woods?ref=bookmarks']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Error

The mistake you are making is that, by calling `append`, you are always adding to the *end* of `friends`.

But for your links, you don't want to add to the end of `friends`, you want to change the value of an element already in `friends`.

## The Solution

You need something more like this:

```
# create your list of friends
for friend in individual_friends:
    friends.append(friend.text)

# for every *i*th link, look up the *i*th friend in `friends`,
# and modify that value, instead of adding to the end of `friends`.
for link_index, link in enumerate(individual_friend_links):
    friends[link_index] = friends[link_index] + '\n' + link.get_attribute("href")
```

## The Better Solution

But this is verbose. There is no need to do two explicit `for`-loops. You need the power of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), which will merge your two separate lists into a single list of 2-tuples and do exactly the same as the above.

```
for friend, link in zip(individual_friends, individual_friends_links):
    friends.append(friend.text + '\n' + link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: Hey Akshat thank you, your answer is soooo close but I had to fix a couple of things, maybe you were not to foresee one of them, firstly `friend` is a WebElement which we cannot concatenate with a string, so we needed to add the `.text` to `friend` when appending. Secondly you missed out adding the `\n` in the concatenation, please edit your answer for me to mark as the correct answer...

Comment: I added the newline character, and added the `.text`.

Comment: great edit to your answer Akshat, you have made it very clear, I still feel you should include the `.text` part and the `\n` part as others may have a similar problem and without basic knowledge of the mechanics. But anyway great answer and thanks!

Comment: @JackHerer I just did.

Comment: Cool, I  thought Iwould maybe do  aproper suggested edit instead, I will mark as answered as this is working great, thanks again.